# clearTimeout on mouseup doesnt work right

Tags: javascript

I want to click on a point and delete it, but when i press my mouse button down for 3 seconds, i want to do something else with this point. My problem is, that the code doesnt clear the timer, it just deletes the point after 3 seconds, no matter how long i clicked it on the point.
Im working with setTimeout and clearTimeout.

````
    function click(event,d){
        timer= setTimeout(function(){
       /* do something */
    },3000)
        }
        function clickRelease(timer){
            clearTimeout(timer)
      }
      divMag1=d3.selectAll(".scatterlayer .trace .points path ")
      divMag1.on("mousedown", click)
      divMag1.on("mouseup",clickRelease)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 - I think you're deleting the target before you can execute what you want.
Note that setTimout may take more than 3 seconds to execute.
Try:

```js
function click(event) {
  const currentTarget = event.currentTarget; // for some reason event.target is null in the timer handler, this fixes it  

  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    currentTarget.removeEventListener('mouseup', deleteTarget);
    console.log('stuff');
    // do stuff
  }, 3000);

  function deleteTarget() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log('deleted');
    currentTarget.removeEventListener('mouseup', deleteTarget); // not required if you're actually deleting the target
    // remove target
  }

  currentTarget.addEventListener('mouseup', deleteTarget);
}

document.querySelector('#but').addEventListener('mousedown', click)
```

```html
<button id="but">Click</button>
```

---

V1:

```js
let timer;
function click(event,d){
    timer= setTimeout(function(){
       /* do something */
    },3000);
}
function clickRelease(){
    clearTimeout(timer)
}
divMag1=d3.selectAll(".scatterlayer .trace .points path ")
divMag1.on("mousedown", click)
divMag1.on("mouseup",clickRelease)
```

Comment: I've tried it , but it still didnt work as expected. The point gets deleted and it looks like my  function with clickRelease doesnt do anything at all.

Comment: Where are you deleting the element?

Comment: @LeonaTheSun what is the point you wrap `clearTimeout` to different function? If you want it like this you should wrap `clickRelease` to event function anyway: `.on("mouseup", function() { clickRelease(timer) })` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare `timer` variable. Then to make your `mouseup` event works on you should wrap `clickRelease` to event funtion again or use it simply:

```
...
.addEventListener("mouseup", function() { clearTimeout(timer) })
```

Working example with button:

```js
var timer
function click(event, d) {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('do something')
    }, 1000)
}
function clickRelease(timer){
    clearTimeout(timer)
}
var divMag1 = document.querySelector('#but')
divMag1.addEventListener("mousedown", click)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() { clickRelease(timer) })
```

```html
<button id="but">Click</button>
```

If you want event to doing something repeatedly while button is down you need to use `setInterval` not `setTimeout` like this:

```
var timer
function click(event, d) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        console.log('do something')
    }, 1000)
}
var divMag1 = document.querySelector('#but')
divMag1.addEventListener("mousedown", click)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() { clearInterval(timer) })
```

Note for clearing interval uses `clearInterval` not `clearTimeout`. Also the `mouseup` event handler attached on whole document in my solution not on button.

Comment: You mean "if you want _repeatedly_ to doing something while button is down...". Not sure that's what op wants

Answer (score 0):

For my use sometimes on touch screen device I added a few things:

1. Implemented long button press using `setTimeout()`/`clearTimeout()`;
2. Used pointerup/pointerdown instead of mouseup/mousedown;
3. Used `addEventListener("scroll")`/`addEventListener("scrollend")` to calculate if screen has been moved 100px (my button height) to execute `clearTimeout(timer)` so the button press can only be recognized when screen is not moving i.e. dragging screen with finger on button and/or when pointerup was reacting too slow.

Comment: Even if it's to say thanks, as it's not an answer, it's not accepted on StackOverflow. Also, I suggest you to check [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting tips